# Two Dimensional Array Not Getting Expected Output

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'll show you first the result I'm having

[image]

The image above is a result displayed in a console by a `Two Dimensional Array.`

So here's the code

```
if ((nArray1 > 0 && nArray2 > 0) || nArray1 > 1)        //Beginning at line 2 of the second column ...
    {
        if (arrTmp[1, 1] != undefined)
        {
            xStart = 1;
            yStart = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            xStart = 2;
            yStart = 0;
        }
        //Primary arrays ....
        for (x = xStart; x <= nArray1; x++)     //record...
        {
            //try 6 here
            for (y = yStart; y < 6; y++)           //field 
            {
                if (RCount == 0)                    //Compare the first cell unconditionally with the next one ...
                {
                    if (arrTmp[y, x - 1] != undefined)
                    {
                        //Hong
                        arrResult11[RCount] = 2;
                        arrResult12[RCount] = 2;
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //Hong
                        arrResult11[RCount] = 1;
                        arrResult12[RCount] = 2;
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (arrTmp[y, x] == undefined) //Check before moving to the next box.
                    {
                        yLastp = y;
                        yStart = 0;
                        break;  //Go to the next line ...
                    }
                    if (y == 0)     //The first column is ...
                    {
                        if (arrTmp[yLastp, x - 2] != undefined) //Moved to a new cell, but if there is a value after the left column ....
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 2;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 1;    //Hong
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 2;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 2;    //Hong                      
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (arrTmp[y, x - 1] != undefined)
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 2;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 2;    //Hong                          
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 1;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 2;    //Hong                          
                        }
                    }
                    if (arrResult11[RCount - 1] == 2 && arrResult12[RCount - 1] == 1)  //If the previous contents are Hong-Cheong ...
                    {
                        if (arrResult11[RCount] == 2 && arrResult12[RCount] == 2)  //Currently, Hong-Hong ...
                            arrResult13[RCount] = 2;
                        else
                            arrResult13[RCount] = 1;
                    }
                    else if (arrResult11[RCount] == arrResult11[RCount - 1] && arrResult12[RCount] == arrResult12[RCount - 1])
                    {
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 1;
                    }
                }
                RCount++;
            }
        }
```

And here's the result I'm having when i tried changing this line of code

```
//Primary arrays ....
        for (x = xStart; x <= nArray1; x++)     //record...
        {
            //try 6 here
            for (y = yStart; y < 8; y++)           //field 
            {
                 //more codes
            }
        }
```

[image]

Please take a look at the highlighted area.

But what I need is this kind of result

[image]

So here's the whole code for that

```
string[] arrPartStr = history.Split(',');

    int[] arrPart = new int[arrPartStr.Length];

    for (int c = 0; c < arrPart.Length; c++)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'P') temp = 100;
        else if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'B') temp = 200;
        else temp = 300;
        if (arrPartStr[c][1] == 'P') temp += 10;
        if (arrPartStr[c][2] == 'P') temp += 1;

        arrPart[c] = temp;
    }

    //20 is the highest possible size
    int[,] arrTmp = new int[104, 104];

    for (int arrTmpx = 0; arrTmpx < arrTmp.GetLength(0); arrTmpx++)
    {
        for (int arrTmpy = 0; arrTmpy < arrTmp.GetLength(1); arrTmpy++)
        {
            arrTmp[arrTmpx, arrTmpy] = -1;  // think -1 as undefined.
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    int intTmp_Ori = 0;    //For storing the result value (100,200,300)         
    int intTmp = 0;    //For storing the result value (1,2,3)
    bool bNextMove = false;
    int nArray1 = 0; //record
    int nArray2 = 0; //Column    
    intTmp_Ori = arrPart[0];
    intTmp = intTmp_Ori / 100;

    for (i = 0; i < arrPart.Length; i++)            //Turns history
    {
        if (i == 0) //If it's your first history
        {
            intTmp_Ori = (int)(arrPart[i]);       //Save current value
            intTmp = (int)(intTmp_Ori / 100);     //P,B,T Value
            bNextMove = false;
        }
        else    //From the second
        {
            if ((int)((int)(arrPart[i]) / 100) == 3)                //Tie
            {
                bNextMove = false;
            }
            else if ((int)((int)(arrPart[i]) / 100) != intTmp && intTmp != 3)//Unlike previous result
            {
                nArray1++;  //Go to next record
                //reset
                nArray2 = 0;
                intTmp_Ori = (int)(arrPart[i]);
                intTmp = (int)(intTmp_Ori / 100);
                bNextMove = false;
            }
            else if ((int)((int)(arrPart[i]) / 100) == intTmp || intTmp == 3)//If it is the same as the previous result.
            {
                if (intTmp == 3) nArray2--;
                bNextMove = true;
                intTmp_Ori = (int)(arrPart[i]);
                intTmp = (int)(intTmp_Ori / 100);
            }
        }
        if (bNextMove) nArray2++;

        arrTmp[nArray2,nArray1] = intTmp;
    }

    int[] arrResult11 = new int[104];  //1 for left value storage
    int[] arrResult12 = new int[104];  //For right value comparison
    int[] arrResult13 = new int[104];  //Array value (1,2) for the result in blue, red.

    int BfResult = 0 ;
    int xx = 0;
    int yy = 0; //Landscape, portrait ...
    int zz = 0; //Let's go over the number of Kan ...

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xStart = 0;
    int yStart = 0;
    int yLastp = 0;
    int RCount = 0;
    int tmpData = 0;

    int intCount1 = 0;
    int intCount2 = 0;

    int undefined = -1;

    if ((nArray1 > 0 && nArray2 > 0) || nArray1 > 1)        //Beginning at line 2 of the second column ...
    {
        if (arrTmp[1, 1] != undefined)
        {
            xStart = 1;
            yStart = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            xStart = 2;
            yStart = 0;
        }
        //Primary arrays ....
        for (x = xStart; x <= nArray1; x++)     //record...
        {
            //try 6 here
            for (y = yStart; y < 8; y++)           //field 
            {
                if (RCount == 0)                    //Compare the first cell unconditionally with the next one ...
                {
                    if (arrTmp[y, x - 1] != undefined)
                    {
                        //Hong
                        arrResult11[RCount] = 2;
                        arrResult12[RCount] = 2;
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //Hong
                        arrResult11[RCount] = 1;
                        arrResult12[RCount] = 2;
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (arrTmp[y, x] == undefined) //Check before moving to the next box.
                    {
                        yLastp = y;
                        yStart = 0;
                        break;  //Go to the next line ...
                    }
                    if (y == 0)     //The first column is ...
                    {
                        if (arrTmp[yLastp, x - 2] != undefined) //Moved to a new cell, but if there is a value after the left column ....
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 2;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 1;    //Hong
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 2;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 2;    //Hong                      
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (arrTmp[y, x - 1] != undefined)
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 2;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 2;    //Hong                          
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            arrResult11[RCount] = 1;    //Hong
                            arrResult12[RCount] = 2;    //Hong                          
                        }
                    }
                    if (arrResult11[RCount - 1] == 2 && arrResult12[RCount - 1] == 1)  //If the previous contents are Hong-Cheong ...
                    {
                        if (arrResult11[RCount] == 2 && arrResult12[RCount] == 2)  //Currently, Hong-Hong ...
                            arrResult13[RCount] = 2;
                        else
                            arrResult13[RCount] = 1;
                    }
                    else if (arrResult11[RCount] == arrResult11[RCount - 1] && arrResult12[RCount] == arrResult12[RCount - 1])
                    {
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrResult13[RCount] = 1;
                    }
                }
                RCount++;
            }
        }

        //Store group 1 results in a secondary array ....
        for (i = 0; i < RCount; i++)//Turns history ...
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                xx = 0;
                yy = 0;
                zz = 0;
            }
            else if ((int)(arrResult13[i]) != BfResult)   //Unlike previous results ...
            {
                xx++;               //Go to next record
                yy = 0;
                zz = 0;
            }
            else    //If it is the same as the previous result ...
            {
                yy++;
            }
            BfResult = (int)(arrResult13[i]);

            tmpData = (int)(arrayBigEyeRoad[yy, xx]);
            if (yy > 5)     //If the field is more than 6 ...
            {
                yy--;
                if (zz == 0)
                {
                    zz = xx + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    zz++;
                }

            }
            else if (tmpData != 0)
            {
                yy--;
                if (yy == 0)
                {
                    zz = xx++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (zz == 0)
                    {
                        zz = xx + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        zz++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                zz = xx;
            }
            arrayBigEyeRoad[yy, zz] = BfResult;
            intCount1 = yy;
            intCount2 = zz;
        }
    }
```

And here's how I display it in `Two Dimensional Array`

```
bsb.makeRoad(history); // Road
    int[,] arrayRoad = bsb.GetRoad();

    string s = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < arrayRoad.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        //just 27 for now
        for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++)
        {
            s += string.Format("{0:D2}", arrayRoad[y, x]);
            s += ".";
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    Debug.Log(s);
```

I hope someone can help me .

## UPDATE

When i tried adding the index of my table like this

```
int[,] arrayRoad = new int[15, 104];
```

The Original is :

```
int[,] arrayRoad = new int[6, 104];
```

I edited my code from this

```
//Primary arrays ....
        for (x = xStart; x <= nArray1; x++)     //record...
        {
            //try 6 here
            for (y = yStart; y < 6; y++)           //field 
            {
                //more code
            }
         }
```

To this

```
//Primary arrays ....
        for (x = xStart; x <= nArray1; x++)     //record...
        {
            //try 6 here
            for (y = yStart; y < 13; y++)           //field 
            {
                //more code
            }
         }
```

Here's the output

[image]

But the problem it i must need to stay with the index `[6,104]` not `[15,104]` .

Comment: your code could really use some refactoring, like moving stuff to a few seperate methods, that you would call from loops providing x,y as parameters, like that its quite hard to understand the flow and how to help, you would benefit too, currently you have LOTS of local variables, which doesn't help much

Comment: @zambari thank you very much for the advice I will shorten my code later on after fixing that last problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it .

```
//Primary arrays ....
    for (x = xStart; x <= nArray1; x++)     //record...
    {
        //try 6 here
        for (y = yStart; y < 104; y++)           //field 
        {
            //more code
        }
     }
```

and setting my result 2d array table to

```
table[6,104];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what your goal is (and very difficult to read your code). This is an example function of how you could write an L into a 2d array:

```
public static void WriteL(int x, int y, int width, int height, int value, ref int[,] array)
{
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    while (o < height-1)
    {
        array[x+i, y+o] = value;
        o++;
    }
    while (i < width)
    {
        array[x+i, y+o] = value;
        i++;
    }
}
```

For instance, you could call it like this to draw an L at position (2,2) that is 4 blocks high and 6 blocks wide:

```
WriteL(2, 2, 6, 4, 1, ref testarray);
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see on my example pictures it is 6 on y axis and 104 on x axis my problem is that instead of `table[15,104]` it should be only `table[6,104]` . But if I do `table[6,104]` it wouldn't let me output the L letter but if I use `table[15,104]` it let me reach my expected output . But I just need to do it on a `table[6,104]` value only.